# Export SAS User data including external identity

Tags: sas, sas-macro

For a migration from SAS to a new BI platform, we need to have a plain list of all registered users, including additional information like the user´s AD name, which is stored as external identity. Is there a way to export such a list from the User Management?

Comment: for reference you can also export users from metadata using this macro: https://core.sasjs.io/mm__getusers_8sas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%mduextr` gives a bunch of user and environment information, including external IDs. The datasets `person_info` and `logins_info` contain this data.

```
%mduextr(libref=work);
```